# xml-rpc API request client

Tags: php, xml, xml-rpc

I have to get some account information from xml-rpc API at sippy softswitch.
http://support.sippysoft.com/support/solutions/articles/77553-understanding-authentication,
http://support.sippysoft.com/support/solutions/articles/107367-get-cdrs-of-an-account but I can't construct my code correctly.
The documentation is very limited and I can't understand a lot.
This is my current code:

```
$urlCdr = "https://portal.mcginc.com/xmlapi/xmlapi";
$post_data = array(
      'username'=> $USER,
      'password'=> $PASS,
);

$options = array(
      CURLOPT_URL            => $urlCdr,
      CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,    
      CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,    // for https
      CURLOPT_USERPWD        => $USER . ":" . $PASS,
      CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH       => CURLAUTH_DIGEST,
      CURLOPT_POST           => true,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => http_build_query($post_data) 
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

try {
$raw_response  = curl_exec( $ch );

} catch(Exception $ex) {
  if ($ch != null) curl_close($ch);
  throw new Exception($ex);
}

if ($ch != null) curl_close($ch);

$cdr = "raw response: " . $raw_response;`
```

It returns nonce realm qop and so on. What should I do after that. Sending this info again to the server?

Comment: Hey, did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
function Callmethod(){
    $url = "https://portal.mcginc.com/xmlapi/xmlapi";

    $method = "getAccountCDRs";
    $params = array('i_account'=>1);//1 is id account

    $post = xmlrpc_encode_request($method, $params); 

    $ch= curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANYSAFE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user' . ':' . 'password');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post );
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT    5.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );



    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $curl_error_no = curl_errno($ch);
    $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($curl_error_no !=0){
        die("CURL Error {$curl_error_no} - {$curl_error}n");
    }

    if ($response_code != 200){

        die("ERROR response code:{$response_code} - {$response}n");

    }

    return xmlrpc_decode($response);

}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why?

Comment: Okay @Thom k. then let me edit my answer, I still studying English and try be short.